# Android-ViewPager Indicator

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

In the below xml code I'm getting the following error:

> "rect" in attribute "shape" is not a valid integer

This is full xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"/>
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home_ico"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/internet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:text="@string/internet"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/servisler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:text="@string/servisler"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kampanya"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
        android:text="@string/kampanya"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/hakkımızda"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="9sp"
           android:layout_marginRight="-9dp"
           android:text="@string/hakkımızda"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/diğer"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
        custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
        custom:shape="rect"
        custom:selected_padding_left="2dp"
        custom:selected_padding_right="2dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_left="2dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_right="2dp"
        custom:selected_width="6dp"
        custom:selected_height="6dp"
        custom:unselected_width="6dp"
        custom:unselected_height="6dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here you go,I uploaded it.

Comment: Try rebuilding. It is possible that the library is not added correctly yet. If didn't work, you can put 0 for oval and 1 for rect.

Answer (score 0):

Available options:

```
public enum Shape {
    Oval,Rectangle
}
```

Use "rectangle" instead of "rect"

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
        custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
        custom:shape="rectangle"
        custom:selected_padding_left="2dp"
        custom:selected_padding_right="2dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_left="2dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_right="2dp"
        custom:selected_width="6dp"
        custom:selected_height="6dp"
        custom:unselected_width="6dp"
        custom:unselected_height="6dp"
        />
```

Comment: Uhmm,I'm confused where should I put it?